# Adding a checkbox in an swt table with columns

Tags: java, checkbox, swt, tablecolumn

I'm trying to make a Java SWT table, with columns.  What I'd like is the left most column to contain a checkbox.  This is the code I've got so far.

```
    panelSelector = new Composite(composite, SWT.H_SCROLL);
    //panelSelector.setBackgroundImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(UniverseAnalyzerItem.class, "/img/LandscapeTools/UniverseAnalyzer.png"));
    panelSelector.setLayout(null);

    ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(panelSelector, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite.setBounds(10, 30, 800, 500);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

    //tableViewer = new TableViewer(scrolledComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.CHECK);
    //table = tableViewer.getTable();

    table = new Table(scrolledComposite,SWT.BORDER | SWT.CHECK);
    table.setTouchEnabled(true);

    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    tableViewer = new TableViewer(table);

    TableColumn uCheck = new TableColumn(table,SWT.CHECK);
    uCheck.setWidth(50);

    TableColumn uName = new TableColumn(table,SWT.CENTER);
    uName.setText("Name");
    uName.setWidth(150);


    TableColumn uID = new TableColumn(table,SWT.CENTER);
    uID.setText("ID");  
    uID.setWidth(50);

    TableColumn uType = new TableColumn(table,SWT.CENTER);
    uType.setText("Type");
    uType.setWidth(50);


    TableColumn uPath = new TableColumn(table,SWT.CENTER);
    uPath.setText("Path");  
    uPath.setWidth(200);

    scrolledComposite.setContent(table);
    scrolledComposite.setMinSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT,SWT.DEFAULT));
```

The problem is, when I run the application the checkboxes are not visible.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not set any input to the table. You won't see anything in the table until you set the viewer content provider, label provider and call `setInput`.

Just as a test adding

```
tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

tableViewer.setInput(new String [] {"line1", "line2"});
```

at the end of your code works for me.

Note: `SWT.CHECK` is not a valid style for `TableColumn`. This is not how you access the checkboxes in the table. You should use `CheckboxTableViewer` instead of `TableViewer`, this gives you additional methods to access to the checkboxes.